# Regex: Find/Match all lines that contains some word or symbol

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I want to find/match all the lines that has `-----`

For exemple:

```
-------- My text-----
blah blah
blah text..
----Other text-----
blah blah
blah
```

My desire output:

```
-------- My text-----
----Other text-----
```

Comment: Use a pos. lookahead: `(?=.*-----).+`.

Comment: thanks,  your regex match all lines that contains `----` and deletes them if I replace all with (empty). But, if I want too keep those lines that have `----` and delete the others, so as to keep only them?

Comment: what will be the regex in this case, please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead (and mind the `multiline` modifier):

```
(?=^.*----).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/in7Y6Q/4/).
For the opposite, you might want to use [a **negative lookahead**](https://regex101.com/r/in7Y6Q/5/):

```
(?!^.*-----)^.+$
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!-{4,}).+\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : start of line
(?!     : negative lookahead
  -{4,} : 4 or more dashes
)       : end lookahead
.+      : 1 or more any character
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```

DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Result for given example:**

```
-------- My text-----
----Other text-----
```